# Return value in cell based on other cells values combination in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a table in Excel that has the following columns:
[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtkuX.png)

[image]

```
dm: Can be 0 or 1
gdr: Can be 0 or 1  
smk: Can be 0 or 1  
agemin: min age number  
agemax: max age number  
sbpmin: min sbp number  
sbpmax: max sbp number  
chlmin: min chl number  
chlmax: max chl number
```

The table is big with all possible combinations.
What i need is a way to find the value in result based on the input of:
dm, gd, smk, age, sbp and chl. As i mention the first 3 can be a 0 or a 1 but the other 3 is a number that must be contain in the range given by the columns min and max.

Has anyone have a clue on how can i solve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the provided table and assuming the parameters for a lookup are in column M (as shown in the below picture), then the formula in cell M9 and copied right to get the result is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($J$2:$J$4,MATCH(1,INDEX((M2=$A$2:$A$4)*(M3=$B$2:$B$4)*(M4=$C$2:$C$4)*(M5>=$D$2:$D$4)*(M5<=$E$2:$E$4)*(M6>=$F$2:$F$4)*(M6<=$G$2:$G$4)*(M7>=$H$2:$H$4)*(M7<=$I$2:$I$4),),0)),"No matches found")
```

[image]